# Can a database be a part of an expansion file in android?

Tags: android

I have a huge database and need to send a database in the expansion file. The file is created previously so want the application to download it after the application executable.

Comment: Do you mean an sqlite database? Yes. It's just a file.

Comment: Yes... an sqlite database

Comment: So... the answer is 'yes'. If you are wanting more specific help with a particular problem, please edit your question and provide detail.